# Proof sets using logic laws

Tags: logic

Prove 
a) (A ∪ B) × C = (A × C) ∪ (B × C) 
b)P(A)(triangle)P(B) = P(AtriangleB)
true for all sets A, B and C? If so, prove it. If not give example if it's false.

I know a it's true but I don't know how to prove using laws of logic?
And how to begin with b?It's false?

Comment: Is the x in a the Cartesian product?

Comment: Yes it's multiply

Comment: As the comments in the other (repetition of this) question you should show what you've done so far. This is to indicate what level the answer need to be at. You see the answer you've got so far is perfectly fine, but it may be on the wrong level (which he can't be blamed for since you've not indicated what level it should be on).

Comment: Also please use MathJax to format your formulas. I've seen you know how to do that in the other question. If you don't know how to format a particular symbol you could use http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html or http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html or https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Answer (score 1):

**a)** Let $(x,y) \in (A \cup B) \times C$. Then $x \in A \cup B$ and $y \in C$. Then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. There are two cases. If $x \in A$, then $x \in A$ and $y \in C$, which implies $(x,y) \in A \times C$, which implies $(x,y) \in (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$. If $x \in B$, then $x \in B$ and $y \in C$, which implies $(x,y) \in B \times C$, which implies $(x,y) \in (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$. In either case, $(x,y) \in (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$.

Since $(x,y)$ was arbitrary, this shows that $(A \cup B) \times C \subseteq (A \times C) \cup (B \cup C)$.

Let $(x,y) \in (A \times C) \cup (B \cup C)$. Then $(x,y) \in A \times C$ or $(x,y) \in B \times C$. There are two cases. If $(x,y) \in A \times C$, then $x \in A$ and $y \in C$, which implies $x \in A \cup B$ and $y \in C$, which implies $(x,y) \in (A \cup B) \times C$. If $(x,y) \in B \times C$, then $x \in B$ and $y \in C$, which implies $x \in A \cup B$ and $y \in C$, which implies $(x,y) \in (A \cup B) \times C$. In either case, $(x,y) \in (A \cup B) \times C$.

Since $(x,y)$ was arbitrary, this shows that $(A \times C) \cup (B \cup C) \subseteq (A \cup B) \times C$.

Therefore, $(A \cup B) \times C = (A \times C) \cup (B \cup C)$.

Comment: By the way, I cannot recommend enough the book *How to Prove It*, second edition, by Daniel Velleman. His book does the best job at presenting the art of proof writing. Everything is done in a very logical and organized fashion, unlike many proof-writing textbooks used in the undergrad mathematics curriculum. You should look at it sometime. There are many examples like the problems you posed.

Comment: But I need it using laws of logic?

Comment: And what about b?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the $P$ in b is the power set operation and 'triangle' the symmetric difference.  Ok, then b is false:

Take $A =\{ 1,2 \}$ and $B =\{ 1 \}$

Then $P(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\} \}$ and $P(B)= \{ \emptyset , \{1\} \}$

So, $P(A) \Delta P(B) = \{ \{2\}, \{1,2\} \}$

But $A \Delta B= \{2\}$, and so $P(A \Delta B) = \{ \emptyset, \{2\} \}$